# Regex allow everything but spaces and underscores

Tags: regex

I want to allow ANY characters except _ and space. I cannot seem to find a "disallow this" token that works.

This works for no spaces
`/^\S*$/`

I thought this might work for no _ but no luck

`/^[^_]\S*$/`

Comment: `/^[^_ ]+$/` should work fine

Comment: @h2ooooooo, that should probably be `/^[^_ ]*$/` instead, to allow for zero-length strings. Otherwise, I agree that this is the simplest, most accurate solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
/^[^_\s]*$/
```

*Pattern explanation*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^_\s]*` - zero or more characters other than `_` and whitespace
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: OP: Keep in mind that you want to switch `\s` out with an actual space if you *only* want to replace spaces (not whitespaces like `\t`)

Comment: When dealing with regex, I almost always prefer `\s` to a regular literal space. OP uses `\S` in the original attempt, so whitespace is meant here.

Comment: If OP wants to ignore all whitespace (tabs, etc), then this is perfect. Otherwise, `\s` should be replaced with a literal space. Depends on the specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `/\s+|_+/g`.

`/`: This indicates the start of the regular expression.

`\s+|_+`: This is a capturing group that consists of two alternatives separated by the | (pipe) symbol:

`\s+`: This matches one or more whitespace characters. \s represents any whitespace character (such as space, tab, or newline), and + means one or more occurrences.

`_+`: This matches one or more underscores.

`/`: This indicates the end of the regular expression.

`g`: This is a flag that stands for "global," and it indicates that the regular expression should be applied globally, meaning it will match all occurrences in the input string rather than stopping after the first match.

Comment: Nice explanation, but I think this is backwards: it will accept spaces and underscore, while OP is asking how to exclude spaces and underscore.

Answer (score -1):

```
^((?!\s|\_).)*$
```

> Try this. This match anything but space and underscore.

Comment: Using a negative-lookahead, inside a capture group, with a quantifier is woefully inefficient. A negated character class, `[^_ ]`, is vastly more preferable.